# Clean coding: how to break loops from inside a function call inside a loop

Tags: c++, coding-style

Clean coding principles generally include a rule that functions must be small and single-purpose.

From Robert Martin's book, Clean Code: "*The first rule of functions is that they should be small. The second rule of functions is that they should be smaller than that.*"

This is difficult to adhere to if I have a function with a complicated loop that contains branches that can break the loop. For example, this code in a chess variant is meant to allow a unit to attack by leaping over another unit on the board:

```
for (arow = row, acol = col - 1, found_obstacle = false; acol >= 0; --acol) {
  if (!found_obstacle) {
    if (cellHasUnit(arow, acol)) found_obstacle = true;
    continue;
  } else {
    if (cellHasUnit(arow, acol)) {
      if (!cellHasAlly(arow, acol))
        _dangerzones.insert(std::make_pair(arow, acol));
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

I understand that you cannot break a loop from inside a function, where the function is called inside that loop.

What is a good way to handle complicated break conditions inside loops in order to maintain clean code with short functions? I can imagine using a special function with a return value to indicate if breaks are necessary, but that still means that each break needs its own function. If I have many break conditions that means the function containing the main loop would still be quite big.

Edit: I am asking the general question of whether it is practical and desirable (from a clean coding perspective) to modularize within-loop code that has a number of break conditions.

Comment: this is a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The `continue` is unneeded (and is incorrectly indented).  Inverting the test on `cellHasUnit` will simplify the loop.

Comment: Alternatively to codereview, consider programmers.stackexchange.

Comment: @IuriiDrozdov In this case, CR would be a bad fit. The OP is asking for general advice on a general problem. CR reviews *specific implementations*. Programmers.se would be a much better fit.

Comment: @Kaz when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info) (besides, over there this will likely be closed as duplicate of [How to tackle a 'branched' arrow head anti-pattern?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/205803/31260))

Comment: Thanks @gnat. You're right, I could've made that advice better.

Comment: Third rule of functions: Reconsider turning it into a function if it's only called at one place *and* you cannot quite imagine any other piece of code ever needing a call to it in the future. Fourth rule of functions: Apply common sense and gather more experience to get a feeling for what constitutes "clean code".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a programmer with above 15 years of programming in several programming languages, I can first tell you that the quote you brought is very nice, you should follow it in order to make modular code, but it doesn't mean each function should be 10 lines of code. That's impossible.

Regarding your code, it is OK. Not complicated. You use functions inside the loop and it looks modular. A break is also OK.

I have one comment, though, using `continue` looks redundant. You could do:

```
if (cellHasUnit(arow, acol)) {
    found_obstacle = true;
else {
    ...
```

Some discourage `continue` altogether because it can confuse. I don't follow this recommendation and sometimes use `continue` but I do try to avoid both `break` and `continue` on the same loop because they have somewhat opposite meanings.

Comment: +1 from me. I think Martin should not present his guidelines as "rules". Having too many functions is exactly as bad as having too few.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe at the `break;` statement, set `acol = -1` and then `continue;` so that on the next iteration, you break out of the loop?

Comment: Thanks and you're right, but in the interests of writing clean code i didn't do that: I thought that would obfuscate my intention.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this form more expressive. It inverts the tests and therefore avoids 2 call sites for the `cellHasUnit` test:

```
#include <map>

std::map<int, int> _dangerzones;
bool cellHasUnit(int, int);
bool cellHasAlly(int, int);

void handleAlly(int arow, int acol)
{
  if (!cellHasAlly(arow, acol))
    _dangerzones.insert(std::make_pair(arow, acol));
}

void test(int row, int col)
{
    int arow = row;
    bool found_obstacle = false;
    for (int acol = col - 1 ; acol >= 0 ; --acol) 
    {
        if (cellHasUnit(arow, acol)) 
        {
            if (found_obstacle) 
            {
                return handleAlly(arow, acol);
            }
            else  // not strictly necessary
                found_obstacle = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The return statement is used to indicate that in this example, the breaking of the loop is also necessarily the end of the test function.

If the real function is longer, then you could write this instead:

```
            if (found_obstacle) 
            {
                handleAlly(arow, acol);
                break;
            }
            else ...
```